# How can any spatially extended object have 4-momentum assigned?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, density

We know that the 4-momentum of a *point particle* is of the form $p^{\mu} = (E/c, p^{i})$, whose transformations across different inertial reference frames are given by Lorentz transformations. However, a *spatially extended object* is not a point particle and therefore has an energy density. The covariant way to talk about energy densities is by invoking the stress-energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$.

Despite this fact, I still see people talk about extended objects (like spaceships and planets) as if they are point particles with a covariant 4-momentum. What I want to know is, how can we possibly talk about the 4-momentum of an object in a covariant manner if it is an extended body with some $T^{\mu\nu}$? Is there some way to start with $T^{\mu\nu}$ and get to 4-momentum $p^{\mu}$ of an object in a covariant manner? If so, can anyone show this in excruciatingly explicit terms?

Comment: Are you interested primarily in flat spacetime?  I suspect that the concept of the "total four-momentum of a system" is not well-defined in a curved spacetime, since you're going to need some kind of integration on a hypersurface to go from $T_{\mu \nu}$ to $p_\mu$ and there's not a preferred set of hypersurfaces in a general curved spacetime.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'm ok with just flat spacetime. Integrating from $T_{\mu\nu}$ to $p_{\mu}$ is what I imagined as well, but I'm not convinced the result transforms covariantly across different inertial frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a particular inertial reference frame with coordinates $\{t, x, y, z\}$, and let $t^a$, $x^a$, $y^a$, and $z^a$ be their corresponding orthonormal basis vectors.  The set of events in spacetime with a given $t = t_0$ is known as a "timelike hypersurface".  This hypersurface is three-dimensional, and it corresponds to all of the events at $t = t_0$ in that particular reference frame.  We can then construct an integral
$$
p^a = \iiint_{t = t_0} T^{a b} t_b \, d^3x
$$
over the $t = t_0$ hypersurface.  This defines the total four-momentum as seen in the given reference frame at the time $t_0$.

However, this construction involved picking a particular reference frame, and it is not obvious that our result is consistent across reference frames.  To see that it is, consider the same integral defined on a surface of constant $t'$ (with corresponding volume element $d^3x'$):
$$
{p'}^a = \iiint_{t' = t'_0} T^{a b} t'_b \, d^3x'
$$
We wish to show that $p^a = {p'}^a$.

Consider the region of spacetime $\mathcal{V}$ bounded by the surfaces $t = t_0$ and $t' = t'_0$.  Assume further that the region of spacetime in which $T_{ab} \neq 0$ intersects each of the hypersurfaces in a compact set, so that we can add timelike hypersurfaces spanning between the surfaces $t = t_0$ and $t' = t'_0$ to make a closed compact region of spacetime.  Let $n^a$ be the unit normal vector pointing outward from this spacetime volume.

[image: A region of spacetime labeled "V". A light blue strip in which the stress-energy tensor is non-zero traverses the region from top to bottom. The top and bottom surfaces are timelike hypersurfaces of constant t and t' respectively. The side surfaces are spacelike hypersurfaces and are arbitrary.]

From the assumption above, the integral of $T^{ab} n_b$ over the timelike "sides" of this spacetime region is zero;  and we have $n^a = t^a$ on the $t = t_0$ surface and $n^a = - {t'}^a$ on the $t' = t'_0$ surface.  Thus, we have
$$
p^a - {p'}^a = \iiint_{t = t_0} T^{a b} t_b \, d^3x - \iiint_{t' = t'_0} T^{a b} t'_b \, d^3x' = \iiint_{\partial \mathcal{V}} T^{a b} n_b d^3 x
$$
But by the spacetime version of Gauss's Law, we have
$$
\iiint_{\partial \mathcal{V}} T^{a b} n_b d^3 x = \iiiint_\mathcal{V} \partial_b T^{ab} \, d^4 x = 0
$$
since the stress-energy tensor is conserved.  Thus, $p^a = {p'}^a$, and the four-vector $p^a$ is well-defined between different reference frames.  (The *components* of $p^a$ as observed in different reference frames are different, of course, but the vector itself is well-defined and constant regardless of the reference frame we choose for the purposes of performing the integral.)

This argument can also be extended to situations where $T_{ab}$ vanishes "sufficiently rapidly at infinity" (rather than being confined to a compact intersection with the timelike hypersurfaces), and it can also be extended to completely arbitrary (non-flat) hypersurfaces in flat spacetime as well.

Comment: I should add that I'm playing fairly fast and loose with notation here, and it's possible that I've missed a minus sign in either my definitions of $p^a$ or my application of Gauss's Law;  however, the argument will still hold since the whole point is to show that their difference is zero.  For more on Gauss's Law in spacetime, see Box 5.3 of MTW.